# Locate Scala installation for Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I'm using `EMR` and can launch `spark-shell`, but I want to run `Scala REPL`. Currently when I type `scala` command on `shell` it says:

```
-bash: scala: command not found
```

How to locate and run `Scala REPL` give that `Spark` is already installed and configured?

Comment: Spark doesn't come with a **plain** Scala installation. You'll have to install it yourself or just use spark-shell

Comment: My current work-around was to dowload `Scala 2.12.5` `rpm` binary and install it using `sudo yum install scala-2.12.5.rpm` as told [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-scala-on-centos-7). But I shouldn't be required to do that, right?

Comment: Spark does not support scala 2.12 yet. Please use scala 2.11.

Comment: Thanx for the tip **@sadhen**. I'm not particular about `Scala`'s version. I would've happily use `v2.11`, if only I could launch the `REPL`. It's just that since I was *forced* to install `Scala`, so I chose the latest available release, i.e., `v2.12.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already [told by **@ernest_k**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549112/locate-scala-installation-for-spark#comment86105759_49549112), `EMR` doesn't come with `Scala` installation.

---

With that said, I used the steps mentioned in [this blog](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-scala-on-centos-7) to install `Scala` on `EMR`

```
# perform customary yum update
sudo yum update

# download Scala installer RPM
wget https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.13.0-M5/scala-2.13.0-M5.rpm

# install Scala RPM
sudo yum install scala-2.12.5.rpm
```